# Pubnub Pings are consuming too much battery on mobile

Tags: mobile, streaming, pubnub

When you unsubscribe from all channels, Pubnub still keeps making heartbeat calls (pings). This results in the application consuming too much battery and data in the background.

Any way to completely unsubscribe and not make any calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been addressed in the latest github repo of PubNub JavaScript SDK v3.7.6. CDN libs may still need to be updated.

So doing an unsubscribe from all channels should prevent any further traffic to/from PubNub network.

Comment: The variable holding the instance is only holding the reference, there is no way to delete an object created once. Nulling the instance will only nullify the reference, the object will still exist. There is no way to destroy a created instance in javascript, I believe. And to support this, I have tested the above and it does not work

Comment: try also `PUBNUB.stop_timers()`

Comment: SDK 3.7.7 solves this problems. Using stop_timers() finally works. Thanks